# StreamBuilder data == null

Tags: flutter

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<User>(context);

    return StreamBuilder<UserData>(
        stream: DatabaseService(uid: user.uid).currentUserData,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          print(snapshot.data); // return null
```

DatabaseService class

```
class DatabaseService {
  final String uid;

  DatabaseService({this.uid});

  //collection reference
  CollectionReference userCollection = Firestore.instance.collection('user');

  //get user data stream
  Stream<UserData> get currentUserData {
    return userCollection.document(uid).snapshots().map(_userDataFromSnapshot);
  }

  //user data from snapshot
  UserData _userDataFromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    return UserData(
      uid: snapshot.data['uid'],
      email: snapshot.data['email'],
      fName: snapshot.data['first_name'],
      lName: snapshot.data['last_name'],
      mobileNumber: snapshot.data['mobile_number'],
      gender: snapshot.data['gender'],
      dob: snapshot.data['date_of_birth'],
    );
  }
}
```

The data that I expected to get is Instances of the object I called.
it return `flutter: null`.

When I tried in my practice app it return `I/flutter (11395): Instance of 'UserData'`

I don't know where the source of the problem, please kindly help. I'm new in Flutter.

Comment: Firstly, you have to check if the data is available or not..like..```builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if(snapshot.sata != null) { print(snapshot.data); } else {print("no data available");}``` hope that solves your issue..reply if it worked for you..

Comment: I already check the data is available or not, the result is the data not available. I'm wondering, why there is no data. I already get the stream inside the database class.

Comment: Well,I believe, that is something that you have to figure out..

Answer (score 0):

As we are using `Streams` it is possible that at the time of widget rendering no data has been fetched yet. So we need to check the state of the stream before trying to access the data like below

```dart
if (snapshot.hasError){
  // access error using snapshot.error
}
else{
  // check for stream state
  switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
    case ConnectionState.none:
    case ConnectionState.waiting:
    case ConnectionState.active:         // access snapshot.data in this case 
    case ConnectionState.done:
  }
}
```

For more reference, you can have a look at the document of [StreamBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html)